# 6 day training split

Tags: muscle-gain, hypertrophy, weighttraining, muscle-growth

I was wondering if my custom training split is effective. It's a mix of an  antagonistic split and push/pull/legs.
I'm an intermediate lifter and my main goal is hypertrophy with a secondary goal of strength.

Day 1 - push
Day 2 - pull
Day 3 - legs
Day 4 - arms
Day 5 - back and chest
Day 6 - legs and shoulders

How can I modify this split?
Should I split muscle groups for example chest days into heavy and light days?

Comment: Why not just a 6-day Push-Pull-Legs? P/P/L/P/P/L/Rest.

Comment: I really enjoy antagonistic workouts, especially arms

Comment: You can always optimize by dropping arm day. I'd argue arm day only makes sense if you are actually a body builder with all the drugs and so on. In that case, ask your coach or buddies instead. However, what is your goal? training 6 days a week is something only a view individuals are able to do consistently, which suggests that you maybe want more than just a decent workout to compensate for your office job ... please elaborate. Anything can be modified, but it's currently impossible to tell from your post what modification would be suitable

Comment: Main goal is muscle growth, and i feel that push pull legs underworks certain muscles due to push and pull days having 3 muscle groups to train and my sessions are only 1h15min

Comment: Muscle growth is too general. How long have you been training? Are you competing? Why do you think your current split is not effective enough?

Comment: My current split has back and legs together for one thing which just isnt a good combo, at least for me. I'm not competing and I've been training properly for a year but did boxing for 3 years

Answer (score 1):

If it suits your goal and it is something you believe you can progress on safely, then go ahead.

If you are unsure, follow a program provided by a professional.